# Flutter - SingleChildScrollView, Column and Expanded

Tags: flutter

I have a UI where there is `SingleChildScrollView` -> `Column` -> `Expanded` -> `ChildOfExpanded`
But I can't put a SingleChildScrollView as parent of Column because of the Expanded. I've tried multiple solutions, like the one on the docs but no one worked so far.

That's the code:

```
Column(
          children: [
            // Other widgets (Containers, Padding, ecc.)

            Expanded(
              child: TabBarView(
                children: [
                  // Other widgets
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
```

I don't have a fixed height, so I can't replace the `Expanded` with a SizedBox or something like that.

That's the error I'm getting:

> The following assertion was thrown during performLayout(): RenderFlex
> children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are
> unbounded.
>
> When a column is in a parent that does not provide a finite height
> constraint, for example if it is in a vertical scrollable, it will try
> to shrink-wrap its children along the vertical axis. Setting a flex on
> a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to expand to
> fill the remaining space in the vertical direction. These two
> directives are mutually exclusive. If a parent is to shrink-wrap its
> child, the child cannot simultaneously expand to fit its parent.
>
> Consider setting mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min and using
> FlexFit.loose fits for the flexible children (using Flexible rather
> than Expanded). This will allow the flexible children to size
> themselves to less than the infinite remaining space they would
> otherwise be forced to take, and then will cause the RenderFlex to
> shrink-wrap the children rather than expanding to fit the maximum
> constraints provided by the parent.
>
> If this message did not help you determine the problem, consider using
> debugDumpRenderTree():
> https://flutter.dev/debugging/#rendering-layer
> http://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/debugDumpRenderTree.html The
> affected RenderFlex is: RenderFlex#7d8dc relayoutBoundary=up12
> NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

I've tried with a Flexible as said in the error, but then I get this:

> Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height. The relevant error-causing widget was
> TabBarView  lib/…/screens/specific_launch.dart:193 ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>
> ════════ Exception caught by rendering library
> ═════════════════════════════════ RenderBox was not laid out:
> RenderViewport#57f46 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
> NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart': Failed assertion: line 1940
> pos 12: 'hasSize' The relevant error-causing widget was
> TabBarView  lib/…/screens/specific_launch.dart:193

In this UI is fundamental to have a dynamic height, so a ScrollView cannot be avoided

Answer (score 4):

With the SingleChildScrollView, your screen no longer has a fixed height and is potentially infinitely long. The expanded takes as much height as it can get, but cannot be infinite. One solution would be to give your Column () a defined height. For example like this:

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        height: heightSum, //try to sum the height of the other widgets
        child: Column(
          children: [
            //other widgets
            Expanded(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Or use Flexible() instead